# What do I need to be able to convert analog video (VHS, or an old camcorder) on a Mac?

Tags: macos, video, tape, vhs, digitization

I have a number of old VHS tapes, as well as some analog 8mm tapes.  I still have a working VCR, as well as the camcorder that recorded the tapes.  I'd like to convert these on a Mac (MacBook Pro) - what do I need in order to digitize these tapes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this with a cheap FireWire gadget called [Dazzle Hollywood](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00006BC2H) - it takes analogue video and converts it to FireWire and then to iMovie it just looks like you have a digital camcorder connected. This is a pretty old device though, so there may be newer/better options out there, e.g. various products from [ElGato](http://www.elgato.com/) ?

Comment: The El Gato video capture (http://www.elgato.com/elgato/na/mainmenu/products/Video-Capture/product1.en.html) seems to work, and has the bonus of working with both Windows and Mac.

Comment: @chris: thanks for confirming that - it may be time to retire my old Dazzle Holywood box and get something better such as the El Gato solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your camcorder has a firewire port, there may be a switch on the camera to switch it to output and connect it to the Mac.

Alternatively you could use [An Elgato](http://www.elgato.com/) product and as a bonus get a TV tuner too.

As @PaulR mentioned, Dazzle also has firewire or USB video capture dongles.

Comment: No digital output on the camcorder - it's about 10 years old.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a USB video capture card. Capture cards rather than TV tuners are hard to find. Here's one that I've tested:

- [Diamond VC500MAC (UPC: 757448022049)](http://www.frys.com/product/7037711)

and another I have not:

- [MyGica iGrabber Nano USB Video Capture Device (UPC: 793573926036)](http://www.meritline.com/mygica-igrabber-usb-2-video-capture-mac---p-38254.aspx)

The software included is [VideoGlide](http://www.echofx.com/videoglide.html), which also supports other devices such as [EasyCap](http://www.undefinedrange.com/posts/console-gaming-in-osx).