# Converting home video tape to digital?

Tags: video, video-conversion, tape, digitization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do I need to be able to convert analog video (VHS, or an old camcorder) on a Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/129852/what-do-i-need-to-be-able-to-convert-analog-video-vhs-or-an-old-camcorder-on-a)

My mother has some old home movies recorded on video tape that she'd like to convert to a digital format. The movies were stored on VHS tapes that have taken on mold and are unable to play -- but she still has the master copies as well as the camera itself. Assuming the master tapes are still good, and the camera can hook into a TV or monitor to replay the tapes there, is there a hardware component I could purchase that could transfer them to some digital format? Either a direct-to-DVD box (a-la recording to a VCR), or a hookup for my computer would be my two best guesses. From her description of the camera, it uses a standard RCA connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this - [What do I need to be able to convert analog video (VHS, or an old camcorder) on a Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/129852/what-do-i-need-to-be-able-to-convert-analog-video-vhs-or-an-old-camcorder-on-a)

The [El Gato solution](http://www.elgato.com/elgato/na/mainmenu/products/Video-Capture/product1.en.html) works for both PC and mac - basically a usb dongle that you plug your analog video source into, and it digitizes it for you.

Comment: Thank you for informing me of the El Gato product! It looks like exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Play the master tape in a VHS Player and use a USB Video Capture (VHS to DVD) cable for input into your computer. Now you only have to save the incoming signal to a file and you are done.
You can get such a cable easily at a shop or at the internet.