# Transferring analog media (VHS casettes, vinyl records) to PC

Tags: conversion, digitization, analog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting home video tape to digital?](https://superuser.com/questions/222321/converting-home-video-tape-to-digital)

I have some VHSs and vinyl records which I'd like to convert to DVDs and CDs, respectively. I have a couple of questions about how to hook the devices up to the computer.

- I've seen some RCA-to-USB cables on the Internet like this one:

  [image]

  Will those work for connecting the VCR to the computer? And what program would I use to take that and save it as a video file?
- Can I connect the phonograph directly to the Line In port in my PC or do I need some amplifier or something in the middle?

I'm using Windows 7 x64, if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get something like

http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/category/category_slc.asp?CatId=1428&name=USB%20Capture%20Devices

and these hardware will usually come bundled with "video capture" software. They will allow you to "record" the video input in a way similar to how you operate a VCR.

2. Depends largely on your turntable. If your turntable operate at line level, then just feed it into the line-in. Otherwise you will need a MC/MM preamplifier. You may or may not need RIAA equalization.

Alternatively, plug the input into mic-in. usually works.

Comment: Thanks, how would I find out whether the turntable operates at line level? I tried Googling but got nothing.

Comment: plug it into linein, if it works then it is at line level